# Insert Into Table Variable CTE

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How to insert the results of a cte into a table variable

Something like this?

```
DECLARE
       @myData TABLE( 
                        Title nvarchar(350) NOT NULL , 
                        Id int NOT NULL ,
                    );
INSERT INTO @myData

with CTE as 
    (SELECT       
      a.Title 
     ,a.Id
  FROM
       TableA
     )
    ,CTE2 as 
    (SELECT  
      b.Title
     ,b.Id   
  FROM
       TableB
    )

    Select * From CTE

    union all

    Select * From CTE2

    Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GetDate() DESC) AS RowId
       , x.* 
       From @myData x
       order by x.Id desc
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
with CTE as 
    (SELECT       
      a.Title 
     ,a.Id
  FROM
       TableA
     )
    ,CTE2 as 
    (SELECT  
      b.Title
     ,b.Id   
  FROM
       TableB
    )
    INSERT INTO @myData  --- insert statement goes here after CTE

    Select * From CTE    
    union all    
    Select * From CTE2

    Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GetDate() DESC) AS RowId, x.* 
    From @myData x
    order by x.Id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

On my SQL2019 edition, the above construct yield no fields inserted. Even worse, if I wanted to use UPDATE after the statement, gave a syntax error.

Instead, this construct was working also in a stored procedure:

```
; WITH CTE AS (
  select ...
  UNION ALL
  select ...
)
insert into @tableVariable(fields..) (select field... from CTE)
```

Hope somebody will make use of this.