# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'

Tags: sql-server, select, subquery

I have a problem storing the result of the query inside a variable using with query.

An error shows that there's something wrong near WITH and then i tried to place a semi colon (;) before with

here's my code

```
        SET @long2 =  WITH QUERY AS (
                       SELECT LONG, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY philtime desc) AS RowNumber
                       FROM TblCurrent_ROI where KMRUN IS NULL and LONG is not null and ACCOUNT = @account
                       )
                  SELECT LONG FROM QUERY WHERE ROWNUMBER = 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert Into Table Variable CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026240/insert-into-table-variable-cte)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH QUERY AS (
    SELECT LONG, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY philtime desc) AS RowNumber
    FROM TblCurrent_ROI where KMRUN IS NULL and LONG is not null and ACCOUNT = @account
)
SELECT @long2 = LONG FROM QUERY WHERE ROWNUMBER = 2
```

Comment: Please explain better your solution